# PHP: Declaring if a value is odd or even from a random integer

Tags: php, if-statement

I don't know where I am going wrong with my code and I am asking for some guidance as I am new to PHP.

I am trying to do an If else statement that will display if the random integer is odd or even. When I run the code it keeps on showing 'Number is odd' or nothing and I am not sure why. Any guidance will be much appreciated.

```
$RandomValue = rand(0, 10);
$OddValues = (1 || 3 || 5 || 7 || 9);
$EvenValues = (0 || 2 || 4 || 6 || 8 || 10);
if($RandomValue == $OddValues) {
    echo $RandomValue, ' Number is odd';
} else {
    if($RandomValue == $EvenValues)
        echo $RandomValue, ' Number is even';
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with dividing by 2 and checking for a remainder? `var_dump($OddValues);` and `$EvenValues` to see the problem.

Comment: since the range is not more than 10 you can use `in_array()` where you have an array of odd or even values and then you check for the values you want

Comment: try `$var % 2 == 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check it like

```
if ($RandomValue % 2 === 0) {
   echo "$RandomValue is even";
} else {
   echo "$RandomValue is odd";
}
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: That's neither the first answer, nor references it any documentation. It's also poorly formatted code.

Comment: i just tried to sort the issue.

Comment: okk so you want your answer to be approved. please tell OP. i am not here to gain points.@localheinz

Comment: Thanks for editing and making it more readable @localheinz

Comment: While this answer is correct, the right course of action would be to flag as duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

There is a much easier way to do this. Use the modulo operator in php which is written as `%`. The modulo operator essentially returns 0 if there's no remainder and the remainder if there is. In this case, you're looking to just divide by 2 and see if anything remains, that's what modulo is doing here. So the only thing it's going to return is either 0 or 1.

```
$x = 3;
if($x % 2 == 0) { //number is even}
else { //number is odd }
```

Comment: While this answer is correct, the right course of action would be to flag as duplicate.

Comment: Except that I think I answered first.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the issue, *this should not be answered, it is a duplicate*. That you answered first is irrelevant, you should have flagged as duplicate. Your answer (and every answer here) is already in the duplicate target mentioned on the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can also check using the bitwise &

```
 $is_odd = $x & 1;
```

Such as this

```
$nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

foreach( $nums as $x ){
   $is_odd = $x & 1;
   echo $is_odd ? 'ODD' : 'EVEN';
   echo "\n";
}
```

Output

```
ODD
EVEN
ODD
EVEN
ODD
EVEN
ODD
EVEN
ODD
EVEN
```

You can test it here

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d47ab3970f24038afb28876b212a6f020eb0a0aa

And for a complete answer to your question

```
$RandomValue = rand(0, 10);

if($RandomValue & 1) {
   echo $RandomValue. ' Number is odd';
} else {
    echo $RandomValue. ' Number is even';
}
```

**PS**. you also have a comma and not a `.` here

```
echo $RandomValue, ' Number is odd';
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e2573a5dfe0e5aec6c0bfac3ce62c6788b070641

And indeed we can condense this a  bit more into only 2 lines

```
$RandomValue = rand(0, 10);
echo $RandomValue. ' Number is '.($RandomValue & 1 ? 'even' : 'odd');
```

Oh and if you are not sure what the `&` "single and" is ( or bitwise in general ):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: Down vote for something that works, lol, ok.  Just because you don't understand it doesn't mean it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Use Modulo.

`if($RandomValue % 2 === 0){ echo $RandomValue, ' Number is even'; }`

Comment: While this answer is correct, the right course of action would be to flag as duplicate.

Comment: Agreed, thanks. I'll be more diligent about that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ternary operator and do the test in one line :

```
function evenOrOdd($number) 
{
   return 0 === $number % 2 ? 'even' : 'odd';
}
```

Comment: this has been answered seven times already, what exactly are you adding here?

Comment: Exactly, I am trying to discourage people from answering duplicate questions. You are not helping anyone by doing so, you are duplicating content which is already on this site, in much better format. If in the future, you remember this moment, and instead of answering an obvious question flag it as duplicate, the net result of our interaction will have been to better this site.